# Create individual pages or dynamically create a page?

Tags: dynamic, content-management-system, web-standards

I'm unsure of what to do here I would like to ask what process should I use or what are the web standards in accomplishing this.

Scenario:

A User inputs information (e.g. a classified ads post). How should I generate the page of the users post? Should I create a new page with the information provided by the user or should I create just one page that dynamically changes with the content requested?

Generally whats the process I should take?

I hear a lot of talk about using cms, but I think I can create my own simple "cms" that can provide my needs. But I need to know what direction should I use. Creating a NEW PAGE or Creating a SINGLE DYNAMIC PAGE?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should be able to create your own "CMS" that will meet your needs. If I understand your question, I would definitely create one page that is dynamically loaded from the database. Think about the server load you could create if you created a new page for every entry. One of the things I advise every client that I develop a website for is to think about what they want their website to be doing for their business in 3 years. I would advise you to think through the same question and I believe you will see why I recommend using a dynamic page. 
Good luck with your site.